# How do I instruct plugin BufExplorer to open a buffer in an existing window?

Tags: buffers, vim-windows, plugin-bufexplorer

How do I instruct Vim plugin [BufExplorer](https://github.com/jlanzarotta/bufexplorer) to open a buffer in a specific existing window rather than open the buffer in a new horizontal (key `f` or `F`) or vertical (key `v` or `V`) window?

Comment: According to http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/, this refers to a "project drawer" approach rather than a "split explorer" which the author prefers.

Comment: Use the plugin's documentation/issue tracker.